# android build image including flash script

Tags: android

Following android official document [here](https://source.android.com/source/building.html), we can run make -j4 to build system.img.

But how can we only run a command to get everything which include all flash needed files (including the flash_all.sh)?

Comment: Are you referring to the driver binaries: https://source.android.com/source/building.html#obtaining-proprietary-binaries

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that before! yes, we need that and it seems AOSP code actually not possible to build out full image. maybe something has been removed (maybe some hardware specific modules).